How do I display all orders made by a customer outside the woocommerce accounts page
I'm trying to create a custom dashboard that would display the customer information and orders they've made, however i don't want to use the default tabbed content provided by WooCommerce as it contains other unnecessary information. How can i extract just the order page. Also note, I'm using elementor to build the custom dashboard
I tried using the WooCommerce docs but the shortcode provided, still shows the accounts page as a whole with all the unnecessary information.

You can use woocommerce_account_menu_items and remove what you dont want in the user panel ? Or just remove the endpoints in your woo settings. There are many examples here and over internet.

Perhaps using someting like this to create your own shortcode?
This code below works, I just hope it's something you can use. WHen you use 'limit' => -1, you get all of the orders without pagination
function custom_orders_shortcode($atts) {
    // attributes for shortcode
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id(), // id of the logged in user
    ), $atts);

    // arguments for getting the order
    $args = array(
        'customer_id' => $atts['user_id'],
        'limit' => -1,
    );
    $orders = wc_get_orders($args);

    // output of the orders, you can customize this yourself
    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $output .= '<li>' . sprintf(__('Order #%s', 'text-domain'), $order->get_id()) . '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('custom_orders', 'custom_orders_shortcode');

